# Linq - How to select items from a list that contains only items of another list?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this two classes:

```
public class Item
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public List<Test> TestList{get;set;} 
}
public class Test
{ 
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public Item Item{get;set;}
   public byte State{get;set;}
}
```

Item Class Data:

```
Id
 1
 2
 3
```

And Test Class Data:

```
Item   State
  1      1
  1      2
  1      3
  2      1
  2      4
  3      2
```

Now i need to write a query that select the Items from my class that just have state of 1 and 2.For example for the sample above it should returns row with Item=3.
i wrote this query:

```
var stateList=new List<byte>(){1,2};
Items.Where(x => x.TestList.Select(c => c.State).Any(s => stateList.Contains(s)));
```

but it returns Item=1 either.Any Idea?

Comment: Could you also add code, that creates `Items` sequence?

Comment: Macropus: Ofcourse not!

Comment: Ilya Ivanov: Why do you need that?!

Comment: Why should it return the row with `Item = 3`??

Comment: to execute your query locally and reproduce your issue. How else do you want us to help you? By the pure virtue of speculation?

Comment: Ahmed KRAIEM: Because  Item=1 has a state=3 and item=2 has a state=4,and as i said i just want to return only the items with state=2 and state=1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This returns the items which all states are in `stateList`, I think that that's what you need:

```
Items.Where(x => x.TestList.All(s => stateList.Contains(s.State)));
```

Answer (score 4):

in case you need only those items which TestList have only items with status 2:

```
tems.Where( i => i.TestList.All(li => li.State == 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue:

This is code:

```
List<string> mds = _userService.GetAllMDUsers();
conf = _context.BillingsConfirmationsView.Where(c=> mds.Contains(c.EmployeeShort.ToUpper()));
```

I am having issue with following situation. Let say I have employee with short "js" and in my mds List I have another employee with short jsc. Now I get back records for both employees and I should get only for jsc since js is not memeber of mds. Now I understand that this is because "js" is subset of "jsc" but dont know how to get correct result. EmployeeShort is string in BillingsConfirmationsView model.

Ivan

Comment: You have posted this as an answer to another question. You will need to 1. Ask another question with the exact content of your answer, but, in addition a description of how your problem is different from the current on and 2. Remove this answer.