# Exluding Items that are in my Exceptions List LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a linq query which is return a list of URLS.   I'm an excluding any URLS that end with a number of extensions such as (bat, cmd, ...).   I have this working with a number of && statements coded into the query itself but would rather  use a defined myExceptions list to give me more flexibility as this list may change and may be used elsewhere in my project.

I want to replace the part of my query

```
  && (!myURL.myURL.Trim().EndsWith("exe")
                                           && !myURL.myURL.Trim().EndsWith("cmd")
                                           && !myURL.myURL.Trim().EndsWith("lnk")
                                           && !myURL.myURL.Trim().EndsWith("bat")                                              
                                           && myURL.myURL.Length > 0 
                                           ))
```

To use a  list of exceptions for more flexibility like

```
 List<string> myExepections = new List<string> { "exe", "cmd", "lnk", "bat" };
```

Reading through other stackoverflow posts I presume I can use the except extension method or Any method with Contains as I've seen throughout the site like

[Linq - How to select items from a list that contains only items of another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297906/linq-how-to-select-items-from-a-list-that-contains-only-items-of-another-list)

But I don't know how to modify my query to do that in this case.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciative.

Here's my existing query:

```
var results = myDataClass.LinksTabke.OrderBy(myURL => myURL.url_Description)
                                   .Where(
                                       myURL =>
                                       myURL.PageID.Equals(QueryStringID)
                                       && (!myURL.myURL.Trim().EndsWith("exe")
                                           && !myURL.myURL.Trim().EndsWith("cmd")
                                           && !myURL.myURL.Trim().EndsWith("lnk")
                                           && !myURL.myURL.Trim().EndsWith("bat")                                              
                                           && myURL.myURL.Length > 0 
                                           ))
                                   .Select(
                                       myURL =>
                                       new results
                                           {
                                               mySectionID = myURL.myTable.mySectionID,                                                
                                               myDescText = myURL.myTable.Desc,   LinkUrl =  myURL.myURL
                                           }).Distinct();
        return results.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:

```
var results = myDataClass.LinksTabke.OrderBy(myURL => myURL.url_Description)
                                   .Where(
                                       myURL => myURL.PageID.Equals(QueryStringID)

                                       &&
                                       //Works for entity framework
                                       !myExepections.Any(x => x == myURL.myURL.Trim().Substring((myURL.myURL.length - 3), 3)) && myURL.myURL.Length>0)

                                       //Works for Linq 2 SQL and EF                  
                                       !myExepections.Contains(x => myURL.myURL.Trim().Substring((myURL.myURL.length - 3), 3))
                                       && myURL.myURL.Length>0)

                                   .Select(
                                       myURL =>
                                       new results
                                       {
                                           mySectionID = myURL.myTable.mySectionID,
                                           myDescText = myURL.myTable.Desc,
                                           LinkUrl = myURL.myURL
                                       }).Distinct();
           return results.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion but unfortunately that leads to the error message "Local Sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implemenatiosn of query operation except the contains operator"

Comment: Ok, It works for me because I'm using Entity Framework

Comment: Got it!  Following the suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712105/linq-to-sql-exception-local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-implementati I slightly modified your suggested query using the contains method instead of Any.

Comment: I was about to change it to:   //...
                !myExepections.Contains(x => myURL.myURL.Trim().Substring((myURL.myURL.length - 3), 3))
               
                    && myURL.myURL.Length>0
                    //...

Comment: Yes please feel free to update it with your suggestion.  Thanks again.

Comment: I have updated the answer with solutions working for both Entity Framework, and Linq 2 SQL, I'm not sure about perfomance, but they work.